# Android - How can I measure performance of ListView and other Views?

Tags: android, performance, listview, frame-rate

How can I measure the FPS of my `ListView`?

See the slides 13-17 from http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about calculating FPS (I guess that should be done system-wide and is not calculated per view), but you can use [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) to profile performance of each `View`. It gives you time needed to measure, calculate layout of, and draw each `View` in milliseconds, and helps you to find slow `View` objects by showing yellow and red circles indicating bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this ListAdapter, which will wrap another ListAdapter and print out log statements about how many views were displayed per second.

```
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class VpsAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    protected int vpsViewCount = 0;
    protected long vpsStartTimeNanos = System.nanoTime();
    protected ListAdapter delegate;

    public VpsAdapter(ListAdapter delegate) {
        super();
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void resetViewsPerSecond() {
        vpsViewCount = 0;
        vpsStartTimeNanos = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public double getViewsPerSecond() {
        final long now = System.nanoTime();
        return (vpsViewCount / (double)(now - vpsStartTimeNanos)) * 1e9;
    }

    public int getViewsPerSecondViewCount() {
        return vpsViewCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return delegate.areAllItemsEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return delegate.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return delegate.getItem(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return delegate.getItemId(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int i) {
        return delegate.getItemViewType(i);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ++vpsViewCount;
        Log.d("VpsAdapter", String.format("VpsAdapter: %.2f views per second (%s views)", getViewsPerSecond(), getViewsPerSecondViewCount()));
        return delegate.getView(i, view, viewGroup);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return delegate.getViewTypeCount();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return delegate.hasStableIds();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return delegate.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int i) {
        return delegate.isEnabled(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {
        delegate.registerDataSetObserver(dataSetObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver dataSetObserver) {
        delegate.unregisterDataSetObserver(dataSetObserver);
    }
}
```

To use, simply wrap your existing ListAdapter in a VpsAdapter, eg.

```
setListAdapter( new VpsAdapter( myAdapter ) );
```

Then call `resetViewsPerSecond()` when you're ready to start timing, and `getViewsPerSecond()` when you're ready to retrieve the result.  The adapter will also log to the console the current vps for every call to `getView()`.

I use this adapter in conjunction with `ListView.smoothScrollTo( adapter.getCount()-1 )` in order to programmatically scroll the listview to the bottom and get the average vps.