# How to get the FPS of my ListView

Tags: android, listview, frame-rate

There are not much questions about it on SOF:

[Android - How can I measure performance of ListView and other Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783176/android-how-can-i-measure-performance-of-listview-and-other-views)

Has a solution to use [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html). But I just want to get the **FPS** on a `ListView`.

**Moreover that Hierarchy Viewer doc states:**

> Hierarchy Viewer can only connect to devices running a developer
>   version of the Android system

And that console doesn't detect my device. And I have no idea what a developer version is.

Somewhere I read Emulators are kind of developer versions, but they **might not be accurate**.

**Also, I found this in my log cat when I scroll the `ListView`:**

> 05-04 11:14:24.697: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20849): [STC::queueBuffer]
>   (this:0x5e74b878) **fps:0.39**, dur:17832.35, max:17194.94, min:17.54

Is that  the **FPS** related to my ListView?

Because it varies from `0.3 to 60.1`

And AFAIK 60 is the max you get.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to subclass a ListView and override its onDraw(), here is a sample code that should pretty much work out of the box:

```
public class FPSListView extends ListView
{
    private Toast fpsToast;
    private long currentTime;
    private long prevTime;

    public FPSListView(Context context){
        super(context);
        fpsToast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    public FPSListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        fpsToast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {          
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        currentTime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
        long deltaTime = currentTime - prevTime;
        long fps = 1000/deltaTime;
        fpsToast.setText("FPS: " + fps);
        fpsToast.show();
        prevTime = currentTime;
    }
}
```